# Append string without hard coded value

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string which looks like:

```
A5050MM
```

What I am trying to achieve is to append the end of the string so it becomes:

```
A5050MM01
A5050MM02
...
```

Currently I am doing this as follows:

```
string sn = "A5050MM";

for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
{
   string appendVal = i < 10 ? "0" + i : i.ToString();
   string finalsn = string.Concat(sn, appendVal);
   Console.WriteLine(finalsn);
}
```

This works but as you can see I am hardcoding the `"0"` because if I don't then the output will be `A5050MM1, A5050MM2 ...` until 9.

My question is there another way to achieve this *without hard coding* the `"0"` or is this the only approach I will have to follow?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try with leading zero: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros

Comment: `string finalsn = sn + i.ToString("d2");` Note `d2` format string - *2 digits*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the overload of `ToString` that takes a format:

```
string sn = "A5050MM";

for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
{
   string finalsn = string.Concat(sn, i.ToString("00"));
   Console.WriteLine(finalsn);
}
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/YNXD88425)

Comment: Hi, I get the following error with this `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'`

Comment: Works fine for me... I've added a live demo link.

Comment: I think it was causing an error because before the edit you had `appendVali.ToString("00"));` and now I did `i.ToString("00")` and it works as expected. Thanks for your help I will accept this as you was the first to answer

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo... Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try using *formatting* (Note `d2` format string - at least **2** digits):

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
 {
     // sn followed by i which has at least 2 digits 
     string finalsn = $"{sn}{i:d2}";
     Console.WriteLine(finalsn);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use also the D2 in toString liek

```
        string sn = "A5050MM";

        for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
        {
           string finalsn = string.Concat(sn, i.ToString("D2"));
           Console.WriteLine(finalsn);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) function

```
    string sn = "A5050MM";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
        string finalsn = sn + i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
        Console.WriteLine(finalsn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 99)
    .Select(x => String.Format("A5050MM{0:d2}", x))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```